# UISlider alpha stuck at 0.5

Tags: ios, swift, alpha, uislider

I have a UISlider inside a cell and I set its alpha to 1 but when the slider is displayed the alpha is stuck at 0.5. How do I change it?

[image]

```
lazy var videoSlider: UISlider = {
    let slider = UISlider()
    slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    slider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.orange
    slider.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.white
    slider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "sliderThumb"), for: .normal)
    slider.isEnabled = false
    slider.alpha = 1.0 // set at 1 here and never changed
    return slider
}()
```

I also tried:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    videoSlider.alpha = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, animations: {
        self.videoSlider.alpha = 1
    })
}
```

Comment: cells are re-used do you play with it ?

Comment: this happens on the very first cell. There is only 1 cell on screen

Comment: You need to set opaque on

Comment: @PranavKasetti I just added **slider.isOpaque = true** after I set the alpha inside the closure, same result. Thanks though

Comment: There are similar threads for this topic, you can take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680473/uislider-ignores-alpha-when-set-to-0-5?rq=1

Comment: @omerfarukozturk I saw that earlier but it only has no accepted answer and only 1 vote so I didn't;t have much faith in it. I'll try it though. Thanks

Comment: the parent UIView also needs to have opaque and alpha =1

Comment: @PranavKasetti The problem was the periodic time observer. For some strange reason it was resetting the slider's alpha to 0.5 every time there was an update. I just had to reset it to 1 on the main queue. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: Ok. Although in your periodic time observer the queue is already main, so you don't need to wrap it inside it again. :)

Comment: That's a weird bug though.

Comment: I noticed that but for strange reason it didn't work when I added it in there without it. Definitely weird bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the period  time observer that was causing the problem. As the time progressed and the track moved along for some reason the slider color was getting reset to `0.5`. To fix it I updated the alpha on the main queue.

```
timeObserverToken = player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { [weak self](progressTime) in

    let seconds: Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(progressTime)

    if let duration = self?.player?.currentItem?.duration {

        let durationSeconds: Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

        // even though this is already happening on the main queue it didn't work without it
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.videoSlider.alpha = 1
        }

        self.videoSlider.value = Float(seconds / durationSeconds)
    }
})
```